# What is the origin of "like there's no tomorrow"?

Tags: expressions

When was the expression "[like there's no tomorrow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like%20there's%20no%20tomorrow)" *as in party/live/etc.like there is no tomorrow* first used and in what context?

Comment: Your research shows ....?

Comment: It sounds like an offshoot of "eat, drink, and be merry, for tomorrow we die."

Comment: I'm closevoting as Primarily Opinion-Based, because there's ***no way*** anyone could meaningfully identify a "first use" for such a familiar concept, or the specific words used to convey it. In which context I suppose all that business about Cinderella's partying coming to an abrupt end at midnight is essentially riffing of the same idea. Plus all those people who've ever said *I'm having such a good time! I **wish tonight would never end**!*

Comment: As if it is the last time you ever will, calling for all inhibitions to be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

The OED registers this:

> **as if there were no tomorrow**, like there's no tomorrow, and variants: with no regard for the future, recklessly; immoderately, to
>   excess.

and cites the following as early usage:

> 1847   People's Jrnl.    All flying onward through the measure [sc.
>   the Polka] **as if there were no ‘to-morrow’**.

Answer (score 1):

1952, Examiner, Taz, Auatralia.

> Joey Maxim's training camp has been padlocked on the orders of his
>   manager, Jack Kearns. "Every time I go away for a few days everybody
>   eats here like there's no tomorrow, e specially Joey," said Kearns.
>   "Chef," he growled, "throw out every box of spaghetti in the joint. If
>   you don't, you're fired." "O.K., O.K.," said the chef.

https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/52881806?searchTerm=%22no+tomorrow%22

There appears to be a worldwide transition from "as if there were no tomorrow" to "like there was no tomorrow" beginning around this time.

Answer (score 0):

[1969](https://books.google.com/books?id=1hJvG5xP7zYC&q=%22like+there+%27s+no+tomorrow%22&dq=%22like+there+%27s+no+tomorrow%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6-aran_niAhVFMawKHYGWA3gQ6AEIRjAG):

> Song by Mrs J B Taylor -- *Love Me Like There's No Tomorrow*

(This is apparently different from the 1985 Freddie Mercury song by the same name.  Plus there's one attributed to Trace Atkins, and one attributed to Roger Taylor.  Don't have dates on those, but they are almost certainly later than the one by Mrs Taylor.)

Comment: A Farewell to Arms, 1932, with Gary cooper and Helen Hayes, probably kept the general idea afloat for fifty years. "Let's love tonight," they said, "There may be no tomorrow!" [A Farewell to Arms (1932)](https://thefilmdetective.tv/video/a-farewell-to-arms-1932/59b86ac487988b15b6002e66/)